# Can I also use 'outsource' to refer to goods, not just work or service?

Tags: meaning, verbs, word-usage

I know *to outsource* is to subcontract work to another company. But for example if company A, a TV maker, wants to buy panels from a panel making company B instead of producing panels themselves, can we say:

> Company A outsources panels from company B.

If not, how else can we put it?

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outsource

Comment: I would say that Company A *sources* its panels from Company B, or that Company B supplies panels to Company A. If Company A used to manufacture panels itself, then I would say that Company A has outsourced its panel manufacturing to Company B.

Comment: Whatever you do, you do not outsource *from*. You outsource *to*. You cannot say, "we have outsourced our customer support from India". That's complete nonsense.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8: This.

Comment: @choster: you should make that an answer. IMO, `source/sourced` this is the typical business usage for acquiring materials for use in products.

Comment: @egdwight is this worth answering if it's been sitting here moldering for six months?

Comment: @marccenedella Absolutely, I'd say. As and when the right answer does come up, it will help the OP and everyone else from then on. OTOH, if the OP has already found an answer, they may post themselves post it and earn reps.

Answer (score 4):

The OED's definition is 'To obtain (goods, a service, etc.) by contract from an outside source'. Panels are - are they not? - goods.

Answer (score 1):

The technical meaning of *outsourcing* is "obtaining **services** from other companies or individuals ***rather than*** employing full-time members of staff to provide them." (See BBC, Learning English, General & Business English [[→](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/work/handy/handy.shtml)])

However, if we admit that panels are *goods*¹, strictly speaking, we could say "Company A outsources panels from company B" only if "A" can produce panel by itself; that is, "A" has the necessary know-how to produce panel, but choose *to outsource* because of the advantages it offers as compared to the traditional process of production. If not, we might say "Company A buys panels from company B".

¹ <sub>Oxford Dictionary of English | *outsource*: "obtain (***goods*** or a service) by contract from an outside supplier."</sub>

Comment: I think even if Company A does have the know-how to make the panels, *buys* is a better word.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, they are referred to as ***bought out*** items. There are contractual differences between outsourced services and bought out items.

Comment: To me "bought out" means to buy the entire stock of something, not to buy it from outside the company. Choster's comment uses what I would use:  "sourced items".

Comment: @Carlo_R Never edit while active exchange is on. That can jeopardize editing by original answerer/ commenting at the answer. I know you're well aware of it.

Comment: I would say they were *bought in*.  *Bought out* has several meanings, but not this.

Comment: In all these weeks there was ample opportunity to google the term 'bought-out items' or otherwise do some research. Note: Without the word 'items' the phrase has an altogether different usage.